# vertical space between div tags

Tags: html, css

I have found related answers on this site but I was unable to find a solution that helped me. I have created the background of my website in such a way that first, I've used a div tag to create the header("HT") then 3 div tags to divide it into 3 vertical columns("lside","cside","rside") where I will be adding different content. Lastly, there is another div tag to make a "footer". The problem is that I'm getting a lot of space after the 3 columns and before the footer. I have not added any margins. How do I remove this gap so that the footer stats from where the columns end?

HTML code-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylemain.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="HT">
<img id="imgHT" src="logo.png" height="100" width="300" >
</div>
<div id="lside"></div>
<div id="cside">

</div>
<div id="rside"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file-

```
body { 
background: #ffffff; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}

a { 
color: #2b2bf6;
    text-decoration: underline;
}   
#HT { 
background: #FFFFFF; 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

#imgHT {
margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

#lside {
background: #ffffff; 
width: 200px; 
height: 750px; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
border: 0px; 
float: left;
}

#rside {
background: #ffffff; 
width: 400px; 
height: 750px; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
border: 0px; 
float: left;
}

#cside {
background: #c0c0c0; 
width: 1040px; 
height: 750px; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
border: 0px; 
float: left;
}

#footer {
width: 1440px; 
height: 70px; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
border: 0px; 
float: left; 
background: #808080; 
clear:both;
}
```

EDIT: FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cWjt8/

Comment: can you make it an fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was the one deleting the answer earlier, didn´t know if i missunderstood your question. Sorry for that.

Why floating a footer?
I guess you wanted something like this, right?

[image]

```
<body>
<div id="HT">
 <img id="imgHT" src="logo.png" height="100" width="300" />
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using a wrapper arround its like:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#wrapper div {
     display:inline;
}
#left {
    background:red;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    background:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    float:right;
}
#center {
    background:green;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

There is no need of floating a footer so far. Its pinned bellow the wrapper.

```
#footer {
width: 1440px; 
height: 70px; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
border: 0px;  
background: #808080; 
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the image so it doesn't work in jsfiddle, since you don't have any margins imma take a shot in the dark, try floating the footer right instead of left.

Comment: yes. that worked. Actually some else just answered that but then deleted it. thanks anyway!